# Display details about user from database

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

I have a system in place where a user logs in based on if their details match what is stored in my database.

Code to loop through the database and retrieve records.

```
    <?php
    // Connects to your Database
    mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db("users_db") or die(mysql_error());

    //checks cookies to make sure they are logged in
    if(isset($_COOKIE['username']))
    {
    $username = $_COOKIE['username'];
    $pass = $_COOKIE['pass'];
    $check = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_name = '$username'")or die(mysql_error());
    while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $check ))
    {
        $username = $row['user_name'];
        $email = $row['user_email'];
    }
    //if the cookie has the wrong password, they are taken to the login page

    ?>
```

Code to display the details.

```
<form action="profile.php" method="GET">


                <p>
                    <label for="your-name">Username</label> <?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?>
                </p>

                <p>
                    <label for="your-name">Password</label> <?php echo $_SESSION['password']; ?>
                </p>
</form>
```

This is the code in login.php where I create the session variables.

```
<?php 
mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("users_db");

if(isset($_POST['login'])){

    $password = $_POST['pass'];
    $username = $_POST['username'];

    $check_user = "select * from users where user_pass ='$password' AND user_name ='$username'";

    $run = mysql_query($check_user);

    if(mysql_num_rows($run)>0){

    $_SESSION['username']=$username;
    $_SESSION['pass']=$password;
    //$pass = $_COOKIE['pass'];

    echo "<script>window.open('home.php','_self')</script>";
    }
    else {
    echo "<script>alert('Username or password is incorrect!')</script>";
    }
}
?>
```

I can display the username no problem for some reason, however the password cannot be displayed i.e. this is purely for testing at the moment so it doesn't matter if I am display the password I will change that later.

Comment: $_SESSION['pass'] !=$_SESSION['password'] your also not actully retrieving anything from the db (as per title)

Answer (score 0):

As Dagon noted, you set `$_SESSION['pass']`, but you try to get `$_SESSION['password']`.

As a sidenote, you seem to be storing passwords in plaintext in your database, which you should *never* do, even if you are just testing for now.

Comment: gosh, which i had seen that ;)